# Weird problem in exploding string with newline

Tags: php, explode

I dont know what's wrong with this PHP code:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE test (
 id mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 filenames text NOT NULL,
 meta longtext,
 added_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)";
var_export(explode("\n",$sql));
```

The code above basically explode the string in $sql with newline char ('\n') and then output it using `var_export`. I have some PHP tests file to worked with the code but not all of them displaying what I hope it would be:

```
array ( 0 => 'CREATE TABLE test ( ', 
        1 => ' id mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, ', 
        2 => ' filenames text NOT NULL, ', 
        3 => ' meta longtext, ', 
        4 => ' added_date datetime NOT NULL default \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\', ', 
        5 => ' PRIMARY KEY (id) ', 6 => ') ;', 
)
```

some diplaying this instead:

```
array ( 0 => 'CREATE TABLE test ( id mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, filenames text NOT NULL, meta longtext, added_date datetime NOT NULL default \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\', PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ;', )
```

notice the difference? the second one displaying it as there are no newline to exploding the string. I don't get what's happening here. Anyone knows something maybe?

Comment: Your editor probably used `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: If this is on a Windows system it could be a carriage return \r or if you're viewing the results in a webpage it could be an html <br />

Comment: Yeah, I think thats the problem, but its weird that several PHP worked like I hope but not the rest, and the weirdest of all is the test files are all in the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be flexible with what a `line feed` looks like. You can make a flexible explode:

```
preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $sql)
```

... or you can normalize line feeds to the format of your choice:

```
$sql = strtr($sql, array(
    "\r\n" => "\n",
    "\r" => "\n",
));
explode("\n",$sql)
```

It's also worth noting that MySQL offers several `SHOW` statements that allow you to fetch most useful piece of data from table definitions. Parsing the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output is often not necessary:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show.html

Comment: What a great solution you have there. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Were all pages created on the same computer? The line ending character code is different for different operating systems. It can be one of the following: `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n`, depending on whether the system is Windows, Mac, or *nix. You may want to check for all three.

Comment: Yes, its in the same computer and same directory too. Yes it worked with \r well. I just know that it actually depend on the OS. Thanks so much, and to solve the problem I will go with Álvaro method above.